# OData routing with WebApi throws exception on Navigation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to enable OData in Web Api. . I created an appoiment class OData routing, and a controller that inherits from ODataController, and I to want to call to my Get method in the controller.

**Code:**

```
public class Appointment : IMongoEntity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentController : ODataController
{
    private readonly MongoCrud<Appointment> _mongoCrud;
    public AppointmentController()
    {
        _mongoCrud = new MongoCrud<Appointment>();
    }


    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Appointment> GetAppointment()
    {
        return _mongoCrud.GetAllEntities();
    }
}
```

**Routing:**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Appointment>("Appointment").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.Id);

    config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());              
    );
}
```

When I run the project, following exception is raised:

> The property  `Id` on type `SaveMyDate.Entities.Company` must be a Navigation property.
>   Parameter name: navigationProperty

Has anybody had that problem before?

Comment: Not sure, but reading this it seems that "Company" is a navigation property (of Appointment) but you don't expose "Company" as an OData entityset?

Comment: What is `MongoCrud<T>`? I can't find a reference to that class anywhere.

Comment: Did you ever get help on this?  I am currently stuck on this as well.

Comment: The configuration of `Company` is not specified and is causing an error. It actually looks like the _Foreign Key_ is not defined in the model and a Shadow property is being used but the cardinality of the relationship cannot be inferred. Adding the FK columns to the model and using attribute notation to link them or using a fluent configuration syntax will help here. However rather than speculate, to properly answer this question we need OP to update with the model for `Company`  and any existing EF configuration that binds the relationship between these two types.